# Server connection delay not recorded on some JMeter clients

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jmeter, response, delay

While testing a webservice we set a connection delay on the server of 5 seconds. Thus you would expect JMeter to give response times >5000ms. In some cases / clients this works fine. As expected, but in others it doesn't.

On some clients JMeter just gives a response time of (e.g.) 315ms, whilst other machines give 5315ms (which includes the 5 second delay). On the problem-machines I also test through SoapUI, same response time, and Firefox. Firefox shows a response time of >5000ms.

Theoretically there shouldn't be a difference between the machines, but obviously there is. I just can't find what.

Answer (score 0):

Please use transaction controller.
All your HTTP/s requests should be part of the same transaction controller.

In order to include the delay time, kindly check/select the property of transaction controller mentioned below:

- "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample"

hope this will help.